# What is a “Nachweis über die getrennte Namensführung”?

Tags: germany, sweden, dutch-citizens

My French wife and my Dutch self got married when we were both living in Sweden.  We have each kept our birth name after marriage.  We are moving from England to Germany and along with my marriage certificate (*Heiratsurkunde*) and a dozen other documents, my next employer is asking for a *Nachweis über die getrennte Namensführung*, which I understand to mean *proof of separated name use*.  From [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namensrecht_%28Deutschland%29#Eheschlie%C3%9Fung), I understand that *Zuerst übergangsweise und mit der Neuregelung des gesamten Namensrechts 1993 endgültig behält bei Nichterklärung eines Ehenamens jeder Ehegatte den zum Zeitpunkt der Eheschließung geführten Namen (getrennte Namensführung) solange, bis die Ehegatten zu einem beliebigen Zeitpunkt gegenüber dem Standesbeamten durch öffentlich zu beglaubigende Erklärung einen Ehenamen bestimmen.*  What exactly is a *Nachweis über die getrennte Namensführung*?  Is it enough to send a copy of her ID (they're asking for mine anyway), or is this a more formal document that we may only be able to get after we will have moved and registered with the *Meldebehörde*?  We could also get a Swedish *Familjebevis* translated (our marriage is not currently registered with Dutch, English, or French authorities).

Comment: You need the marriage certificate. This is all about determining the income tax class the employer has to adher to.

Comment: @Janka Yes, I understand I need the marriage certificate (although I've asked whether an extract from civil registry that shows we are married may suffice as well). But *apart* from the marriage certificate, they are *also* asking for a “ggf. Nachweis über die getrennte Namensführung” as a separate item.